# How to check if variable is set && .length>x in same ()?

Tags: javascript

I want to check that a variable exists and that it its length is greater than a particular number within a single if statement.  I can achieve the desired result by doing:

```
if(v){
    if(v.length>3)
        //do thing
}
```

But if I try to just do:

```
if(v.length>3)
    // do thing
```

I bug out when v is not declared.  Similarly if I try to do:

```
if(v&&v.length>3)
```

I bug out.  How do I achieve the desired result most readably?

Comment: try `if (v && v.length && v.length > 3)` ... under what circumstances do you "bug out" in the last code snippet?

Comment: @JaromandaX You are wrong: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/406544/47097316/

Comment: that's why I didn't put it as an answer ... however, the first code snippet in the question would not work either, so, I can't be wrong with respect to the question asked

Comment: what would help is knowing a little more about `v`, is it an argument in a function? is it declared as a var anywhere?

Comment: Effectively, there is no difference between`if(v){
    if(v.length>3) {} } ` and `if(v&&v.length>3) {}` . If `v` is not defined both should throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: @COMisHARD Your third version should work fine. If it does not, there is something else wrong with your code or design.

Comment: @MattWay I'm wondering the same thing. Without an example for the 3rd version "bugging out" both my and other answers are overkill - unless it is in strict mode?.

Answer (score 3):

A final answer depends on how generic you want the solution. While `.length` is shorthand notation for looking up an object property named "length", it must be applied to an object value. But the `typeof` operator returns "function" for a function object, and "object" for `null` - which is not an object data type and will crash if you attempt to look up a property on it. Oh, and primitive string values promote to a String object with a length property.

So, a generic solution could look like

```
if(v && typeof v == "object" || typeof v == "function" || typeof v == "string" && v.length > 3)
{   // do stuff
}
```

where the test for `v` being truthy excludes `v` having a value of `null`. *But* notice that if you can exclude function objects (which have a `length` property giving the number of arguments they expect) and string values you could shorten this to

```
if(v && typeof v == "object" && v.length > 3)
```

Note that if the length property does not exist it will return a value of `undefined` and `undefined > 3` is false.

---

Update after question comment:

```
    if(v)
```

can fail in strict mode if `v` has never been defined. This could be the result of defining `v` using a `let` or `const` statement executed after the `if` statement. Either execute the let or const statement first or declare `v` using a `var` statement in scope of the testing code.